# Read out text file until first empty line is found

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted, fancyvrb, catchfile

Im currently writing a manual for a package and wanted to include parts of a Matlab file.

I was able to display the whole file with the listings package but my goal is to only display the first part of it until the first empty line ist found.

Preferably the comment symbol "%" at the beginning of each line should be deleted/ignored.

I found some implementations that can take parts of files by using line numbers, so just finding the line number of the empty line should do the trick.

Is there a way to extract parts of a file like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You might have a better chance of someone helping if you provide a concrete example of what you are referring to.

Comment: To follow up on @Troy, for example, some don't know what a MATLAB file might contain.  That itself could affect the approach.

Comment: In what format do you want the result to be displayed (simple verbatim code, lstlisting etc.)? Also, please add a sample Matlab file as requested